# Wrappin a "select" listing

Tags: jquery

How can I wrap this

```
        <select class="mymenu">
    <option class="mymenu" value="test">sample</option>
<option class="mymenu" value="test">sample</option>

</select>
```

with `<form class="mystyle" />`

I tried it with wrapInner but it only works for id or classes.

```
$("select").wrapInner('<form class="mystyle" />');
```

But this doesn't work.

I want to use it for a responsive design...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `.wrap()`

```
$("select").wrap('<form class="mystyle" />');
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/HhMjn/1/

Comment: Hi pXL, thanks for your reply. But this doesn't work... I tried it with " 'select' " and " "select" "...

Comment: mmhh..yes, it should work but I don't know why, it doesn't. The "select" is inside a div... but normally both of your answers should work...

Comment: Oh! Sorry. It's working now. I had different stuff in my function going on. I changed the position of the code and now it's working like it should. Great and thank you very much for all you help and hints. AD